# Manage abstract classes in std container

Tags: c++, c++11

After a lot of research I still don't understand how to deal with an abstract class collection with smart pointers.

Here are the errors I got:

```
error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Shape; _Dp = std::default_delete<Shape>]'
   base_ptr s = shapes.front();

error: no matching function for call to 'std::unique_ptr<Shape>::unique_ptr(Shape&)'
   shapes.push(base_ptr(b));
```

By compiling the minimal code to replicate the error ([code online avaiable](http://cpp.sh/3prwi)).

```
    #include <queue>
    #include <memory>

    class Shape {
    public:
        virtual int getPerimeter() =0;
    };

    typedef std::unique_ptr<Shape> base_ptr;

    class Circle : public Shape {
    public:
        virtual int getPerimeter() { return 1; };
    };

    class Square : public Shape {
    public:
        virtual int getPerimeter() { return 0; };
    };

    class ShapeManager {
    public:
        ShapeManager();
        void useShape() {
            if(shapes.empty())
                throw "Work stack is empty.";

            base_ptr s = shapes.front();
            s->getPerimeter();
            shapes.pop();
        }

        void submitShape(Shape &b) {
            shapes.push(base_ptr(b));
        }
    private:
        std::queue<base_ptr> shapes;
    };

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        ShapeManager s();
        Circle c;
        s.submitShape(c);
        s.useShape();
        return 1;
    }
```

It works if I declare the `queue` as `queue<Shape*>` but I don't want to deal with pointers -meaning *.

**EDIT**, this code compiles. Thanks everyone. [This article](http://shaharmike.com/cpp/unique-ptr/) suggested by [Guillaume Racicot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2104697/guillaume-racicot) helps seeing clearer the situation.

```
#include <queue>
#include <memory>

class Shape {
public:
    virtual int getPerimeter() =0;
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<Shape> base_ptr;

class Circle : public Shape {
public:
    Circle() {};
    virtual int getPerimeter() { return 1; };
};

class Square : public Shape {
public:
    virtual int getPerimeter() { return 0; };
};

class ShapeManager {
public:
    ShapeManager();
    void useShape() {
        if(shapes.empty())
            throw "Work stack is empty.";

        base_ptr s = std::move(shapes.front());
        s->getPerimeter();
        shapes.pop();
    }

    void submitShape(base_ptr b) {
        shapes.push(std::move(b));
    }
private:
    std::queue<base_ptr> shapes;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ShapeManager s;
    base_ptr c = std::make_unique<Circle>();
    s.submitShape(std::move(c));
    s.useShape();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: if you dont want to deal with pointers, then what do you want? You definitely cannot have objects, because there arent any `Shape` objects. Maybe references? Then [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) might help

Comment: I meant I don't want to deal with *. Since smart pointers exists.

Comment: You cannot use unique_ptrs this way. They are owning and non-copyable, and you are trying to copy `base_ptr s = shapes.front();` and transfer ownage `s.submitShape(c);`. This kind of usage is incompatible with unique_ptr. You can try with shared_ptrs.

Comment: Circle is not allocated with new. Smart pointer manage objects allocated with new. What schould happen in your submitShape function?

Comment: Vexing parse for `ShapeManager s();`, may be `ShapeManager s;`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if you don't want to deal with pointers, why don't you just use `queue<Shape>` and avoid `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` completely for this?

Comment: @TriskalJM it can't work. This is not Java.

Comment: I don't see any need for you to extract the `unique_ptr`, just use references: `base_ptr& s = shapes.front();`.

Comment: @Jarod42: That is not the most vexing parse.

Comment: As for your `submitShape`, don't pass in references. The goal of smart pointers is to *manage pointers*, so give it a pointer to manage: `s.submitShape(new Circle());`.

Comment: Isn't this one of the primary examples of using pointers? Subclasses in a container that are all treated the same.

Comment: @Deewy smart pointer replaces raw owning pointer. However, there is no replacement for raw observing pointer. There is nothing wrong with raw pointers, as long as they are not owning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The container is a distraction. The problem is that `unique_ptr` is not copyable; if it were, it wouldn't be unique. So you probably need to add a call to `std::move`:

```
base_ptr s = std::move(shapes.front());
```

This means something different from what the original code might have been intended to do; it removes the object from the container. If that's not what you wanted, then `std::move` isn't the right answer and, probably, `unique_ptr` is not the right mechanism.

Comment: This is just one part of the problem. See my comment above.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also tried `std::shared_pointer` and have the same kind of error. Would it be more appropriate to use smart or shared pointer in this example ?

Comment: @Deewy -- impossible to say without a discussion of your design goals. You posted a coding problem, and there are several possible solutions to that problem. Your design question probably ought to be asked as a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

There are many problems in your example, not just misuse of smart pointers. First, the most obvious once is your declaration of `s`:

```
ShapeManager s();
```

This declares a function named `s` that returns a `ShapeManager` and takes no parameter.

Maybe you meant to declare an object of type `ShapeManager`?

```
ShapeManager s{};

// Or

ShapeManager s;
```

Secondly, you are misusing smart pointer. You have a queue of unique pointer. A unique pointer is a RAII wrapper around a free store allocated object. That means that it's a wrapper that is constructed with an object allocated with `new`. In your example, you're not doing that. You are constructing unique pointer with an object that has automatic storage.

A smart pointer that points to a automatic storage allocated object is the observer pointer: is must not own, delete or try to manage anything about that object. In fact, observer pointer is a language feature instead of a library one. It's commonly called a *pointer*.

This is your code with usage of observer pointers:

```
template<typename T>
using observer_ptr = T*;

struct ShapeManager {
    void useShape() {
        if(shapes.empty())
            throw "Work stack is empty.";

        auto s = shapes.front();

        s->getPerimeter();
        shapes.pop();
    }

    void submitShape(Shape &b) {
        shapes.push(&b);
    }

private:
    std::queue<base_ptr> shapes;
};

int main() {
    ShapeManager s;
    Circle c; // Automatic storage
    Rectangle r; // Automatic storage too.

    s.submitShape(c);
    s.submitShape(r);
    s.useShape();
}
```

However, you might not want to hold them using automatic storage. My guess is you want to use `std::unique_ptr` everywhere instead. This allow the object submitted to the shape manager to outlive it's scope. For that you'll need to allocate objects on the free store. The most common way is to use `std::make_unique`:

```
struct ShapeManager {
    void useShape() {
        if(shapes.empty())
            throw "Work stack is empty.";

        // We must create a reference,
        // Using simply auto would require copy,
        // Which is prohibited by unique pointers
        auto&& s = shapes.front();

        s->getPerimeter();
        shapes.pop();
    }

    void submitShape(base_ptr b) {
        shapes.push(std::move(b));
    }

private:
    std::queue<base_ptr> shapes;
};

int main() {
    ShapeManager s;

    // Allocated on the free store,
    // The lifetime of c and r are managed by
    // The unique pointer.
    auto c = std::make_unique<Circle>();
    auto r = std::make_unique<Rectangle>();

    s.submitShape(std::move(c));
    s.submitShape(std::move(r));
    s.useShape();
}
```

Comment: I updated the final code with your suggestion, adjusted (changed the parameters of submitShape to not use std::move everytime) Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Deewy implicitly moving a unique pointer is dangerous. When you will have segfaults, check that first because it's extremely error prone. I would not allow such code pass reviews.

Comment: Thanks for all those precisions. I'll read more about this since I am obviously confused. Do you know an article or documentation that can help on this ?

Comment: I am very grateful for the time you spent. Thanks again.